# receive USSD code through serial port

Tags: c++, c, ussd

I am writing a C++ application that can send and receive AT&T USSD codes to and from a phone connected to a PC through usb (serial communication).

The problem I have is, after sending some USSD code request to the phone, I don't know the **condition** that makes me stop read listening.

What is the general AT&T USSD code receive format if there is any.
because if I don't setup a receive condition, my read code will last forever.

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Wikipedia: _A typical USSD message starts with an asterisk (*) followed by digits that comprise commands or data. Groups of digits may be separated by additional asterisks. The message is terminated with a number sign (#)._

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, I know that, I can send USSD message without * and # using serial port communication, example `port.write("AT+CIMI");`.  The problem is how to handle its received data request (how to know if it has finished the response),  WHEN TO STOP READING THE RESPONSE!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the stop condition is **<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>** or **<CR><LF>ERROR<CR><LF>**